# Correct way to double a class instance with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to make a test double for a class instance with RSpec.  Say I have a test that only accepts a File object as an argument.

Great, now how do I make a double so I don't have to pass in an actual file with all of my specs?

```
let(:file) { double(File) }
raise "NOT A FILE" unless file.is_a? File
# => RuntimeError: NOT A FILE
```

I've also tried this:

```
let(:file) { instance_double(File) }
raise "NOT A FILE" unless file.is_a? File
# => RuntimeError: NOT A FILE
```

And this (which is expecting an actual file):

```
let(:file) { object_double(File.new) }
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just stub the `is_a?` call.

```
file = instance_double(File)
allow(file).to receive(:is_a?).with(File).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is true you can stub `#is_a?`. But I would say, instead of trying to figure out *what* object it is, you could try to figure if it knows *how* to do the thing you need to do.

For instance, instead of `received_file.is_a?(File)`, you could do `received_file.respond_to?(:write)`.

This way, you can pass a `Tempfile`, or a `File`, or even an RSpec `InstanceDouble(File)`. If the class knows how to `#write` then, we trust it.